# API Gateway call giving forbidden error even with execute-api interface

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

```
status=403 error=b'{
"errors": [
    {
        "message": "Forbidden"
    }
]
```

}'

When I am doing an api call I am getting Forbidden error even though I have declared my execute-api interface for the vpc

Comment: What are you trying to do with the API Gateway? what is on the other end of the gateway? what exact steps have you taken so far?

Comment: I using the api gateway url in my glue job script. and making a get call to the api, by passing the x-api-key to it, it used to work fine when my security groups were open to all internet 0.0.0.0/0 but now since I am trying to make it more secure, I have to cut the IP range and hence use vpc endpoints interface for execute-api. and the endpoints are been declared outbound rules for another security group used by the glue connection. But now when I make a GET call I get the forbidden message. The api works perfectly fine if I try it manually with curl though to verify if the api is not broken.